# How to access/create C# xsd autogenerated fields

Tags: c#, xsd

I have a set of classes generated from an XSD by XSD.exe.  I'm trying to populate some of the fields on those classes dynamically by reading data from a CSV file.  The issue I'm having is that any properties that represent other generated classes are not instantiated when the root object is created, so they are simply null.

So for example if I create an instance "doc" of my root document Main_Message that has a property "field1" of type Sub_Message, doc.field1 is null, so if I try to set doc.field1.name, I will get an exception.

My first thought on how to solve this problem is to do create-on-read for those object properties.  Since the generated classes are partial classes, I could do this manually for every generated class, modifying the property getters.  However I really want to avoid that approach.  There are a lot of generated classes, and I don't want to have to maintain my modified version any time the XSD changes.

My next thought was to do the create-on-read external to the classes in my code that is reading the CSV data.  I would first read the property, and if it is null, create an instance of the class and assign it to that property, then set the field on that property.  However I'm not sure how to do that.  I could create an instance of the class using Activator.CreateInstance(propertyType), but that returns a basic object reference, which I cannot assign to the property without a cast.  However I don't have the type name at compile time, so I can't do that cast.

So I'm trying to figure out how to deal with these generated classes to read field values from a CSV file and populate fields on the document objects, then use those to create XML.  I'm stumped at the moment on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after much searching I found a working solution.

```
public static T Cast<T>(object o)
{
  return (T)o;
}

obj = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(MainClass).GetMethod("Cast").MakeGenericMethod(prop.PropertyType);
prop.SetValue(parent, castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { obj }), null);
```

So I am able to create and assign the properties as needed at runtime.